# PostGraphile and Swift (SwiftUI) Integration

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, postgraphile

I am looking to build a client for a website, the api the website provides is with postGraphile https://api.twetch.app/v1/graphiql . I have been struggling to integrate this with Swift. If anyone has any resources on this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a full GraphQL client on iOS the easiest way is [Apollo iOS](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios)

There is a little bit of setup but it will let you query your API easily and give you auto completion and caching strategies.

You can of course query the API manually too but it will require quite a bit more work.